# Как соединить два массива на php?

Tags: php, phpquery

С помощью phpQuery спарсил данные, нужно привести их к такому виду:

Storefront - Operational

Checkout - Operational

Control Panel - Operational

API - Operational

Help Center - Operational

Billing - Operational

Мой вариант

require_once 'phpQuery-onefile.php';

```
    $html =  file_get_contents('https://status.ecwid.com/');
    $document = phpQuery::newDocument($html);
    $statusNames = $document->find('.name');
    $statuses = $document->find('.component-status');
    
    
    
    foreach($statusNames as $elem) {
        $name = pq($elem)->html();
        echo $name . ' - ';
        foreach($statuses as $elem2) {
            
            $status = pq($elem2)->html();
            echo  $status . '<br>';
            break;
        }
    }
```

Это неправильно так как второй foreach всегда будет давать только первый $status из-за команды break. Может кто-нибудь знает как это по уму сделать?

Comment: наведите пример входящих данных

Comment: и желаемый результат

Comment: "только первый $status из-за команды break" - ну так уберите его. В чём проблема?)